# fetch res.json() working with await and async but not working with promises

Tags: asynchronous, async-await, promise, fetch

I have always been made to believe that **async and await** and **promises** were one and the same thing, here, in my code, res.json() is working with await but isnt working at all with .then(). maybe I am missing something. please this is not a duplicate question. I have been scouring the internet for answers for the most part of two days now.

Here is the code with .then, aync and await, and i will also include the code from my server that sends the json

**CODE USING .then()**

```
const requestURL = "/auth/profile";

const request = new Request(requestURL, {
    method: 'POST'
});
fetch(request)
    .then( (res) => {
        res.json()
    })
    .then(obj => {
        console.log(obj)
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log(err)
    })
```

here, console.log(obj) logs *undefined*

**CODE USING ASYNC AND AWAIT**

```
const requestURL = "/auth/profile";

const request = new Request(requestURL, {
    method: 'POST'
});
fetch(request)
    .then( aync (res) => {
        const obj = await res.json()
        console.log(obj)
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log(err)
    })
```

here, console.log(obj) logs the correct json object as expected

**server request handler (nodejs)**

```
const getProfile = async (req, res, next) => {
    
    const result = JSON.stringify({"status":"not logged in", "body": "there is a big poblem"})

    res.setHeader('content-type', 'application/json');
    
    res.status(200).send(result)

}
```

While I have used other tools to make sure I have the response from my server properly set up, if i am missing something kindly indicate to me, cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in your handling of of the chains.  You need to return data to the next then, it's not automatic and varies depending on scope.  Change to:

```
fetch(request)
.then( (res) => {
    // Process.. then return some data to the next chain in line.
    return res.json()
})
.then(obj => {
    // Now, obj will be what the line above 'returned'
    console.log(obj)
})
.catch(err => {
    console.log(err)
})
```